# Operator precedence and associativity in C#

Tags: c#

I've two lines of coding as below

```
int? i = 1;
int j = i ?? 2 +1;

now "j is 1"

int? i = 1;
int j = (i ?? 2) +1;

now "j is 2"
```

Could you explain how?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691323%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Comment: it's actually rather obvious

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure - it's simple a matter of precedence. The (Microsoft) C# specification lists operator precedence in section 7.3.1 (in the C# 4 and C# 5 specifications, anyway; it's 7.2.1 in the C# 3 spec), although that's only really an informative table - it's really governed by the grammar.

Anyway, the null-coalescing operator (`??`) has lower precedence than the binary addition operator (`+`) so your first code is equivalent to:

```
int? i = 1;
int j = i ?? (2 + 1);
```

As the value of `i` is non-null, the right hand operand of the null-coalescing operator isn't even evaluated - the result of `i ?? (2 + 1)` is just 1.

Compare that with your second example, where the null-coalescing operator expression again evaluates to 1, but then 1 is added to the result of that. It's effectively:

```
int tmp = i ?? 2; // tmp is now 1
int j = tmp + 1;  // j is 2
```

Associativity is irrelevant here, has it only controls the ordering/grouping when an operand occurs between two operators with the same precedence.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you will understand it better without the use of the [??](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx) operator

**Scenario 1:**

```
int? i = 1;
int j;
if (i != null)
{
    //i is not null so this is hit
    j = i;
}
else
    j = 2 + 1;
}
```

So j = **1**

**Scenario 2:**

```
int? i = 1;
int j;
if (i != null)
{
    //i is not null so this is hit
    j = i;
}
else
    j = 2;
}
```

So j = 1

```
//No matter the result of the above if, 1 is always added.
j = j + 1;
```

So j = **2**

Answer (score 0):

```
int? i = 1;
int j = i ?? 2 + 1; //If I is null make j = to 3
```

Now j is 1

```
int? i = 1;
int j = (i ?? 2) + 1;  //If I is null make j = 2 else make j = to 0 and then add 1
```

Now j is 2